# undefined method `dig' for #<String:0x007f91d8579308>

Tags: ruby, rspec

I want to use dig in order to get XML tag value. I tried this:

```
new_xml_body = Nokogiri::XML(new_xml)
new_trx_id = new_xml_body.search('transaction_id').first.text
```

Using dig:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'nori'
require 'pry'
require 'active_model'
require 'ruby_dig'
new_xml_body = Nokogiri::XML(new_xml)
new_trx_id = new_xml_body.dig('transaction_id')
```

But I get:

```
NoMethodError:
       undefined method `dig' for #<String:0x007f91d8579308>
```

Can you propose some solution of the problem?

Comment: What is inside `new_trx_id`? And what do you think `#dig` does?

Comment: @ndn it should store very long string

Comment: Please provide [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you want comprehensive help.

Comment: You parse xml using `nokogiri` or `nori`? Are there any code between `new_xml_body = Nokogiri::XML(new_xml)` and the last line?

Comment: `new_xml_body.search('transaction_id').first.text` obviously returns a string. You cannot call `dig` on a string. What do you think `new_xml_body.search('transaction_id').first.text` returns? What do you try to achieve by calling `dig`?

Comment: *I want to use dig in order to get XML tag value* -- Why don't you just use nokogiri for that?  After all, that is what nokogiri is for.   The ruby_dig docs state that dig is a method for Hashes or Arrays, yet you are calling dig() on the return value of Nokogiri::XML(), which is neither a Hash nor an Array, hence the error.

Comment: @7stud Can you show me working example please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nokogiri search example:

```
require 'nokogiri'

xml_doc  = Nokogiri::XML %q{
<root>
  <aliens>
    <alien>
      <name>Alf</name>
    </alien>
    <human>
      <name>Peter</name>
    </human>
    <alien>
      <name>Bob</name>
    </alien>
  </aliens>
</root>
}

alien_names = xml_doc.xpath('//alien/name/text()')

alien_names.each do |name|
  puts name
end

--output:--
Alf
Bob
```

And:

```
xml_doc  = Nokogiri::XML %q{
<root>
  <aliens>
    <alien planet="Mars">
      <name>Alf</name>
    </alien>
    <human>
      <name>Peter</name>
    </human>
    <alien planet="Alpha Centauri">
      <name>Bob</name>
    </alien>
  </aliens>
</root>
}

alien_names = xml_doc.xpath('//alien[@planet="Alpha Centauri"]/name/text()')

alien_names.each do |name|
  puts name
end

--output:--
Bob
```

If you know css, you can also use [css selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp):

```
name_tags = xml_doc.css('alien > name')

name_tags.each do |name_tag|
  puts name_tag.text
end

--output:--
Alf
Bob
```

**Response to comment**:

`Rails` has a `Hash#from_xml()` method.  Here is an example using `dig()`:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/hash/conversions'
require 'pp'

xml = %q{
<aliens>
  <alien planet="Mars">
    <name>Alf</name>
  </alien>
  <human>
    <name>Peter</name>
  </human>
  <alien planet="Alpha Centauri">
    <name>Bob</name>
  </alien>
</aliens>
}

hash = Hash.from_xml(xml)   #rails method
pp hash
p hash.dig 'aliens', 'human', 'name'
p hash['aliens']['human']['name']

--output:--
{"aliens"=>
  {"alien"=>
    [{"planet"=>"Mars", "name"=>"Alf"},
     {"planet"=>"Alpha Centauri", "name"=>"Bob"}],
   "human"=>{"name"=>"Peter"}}}

"Peter"
"Peter"
```

If you need to run the xml string through nokogiri first, then just do

```
doc = Nokogiri:XML(xml)
string = doc.to_s
hash = Hash.from_xml(string)
...
```

Comment: You can't use dig() on the return value of Nokogiri::XML(), so no I cannot show you an example.  What is your preoccupation with dig() -- it's an irrelevant method to begin with that provides nothing new to the ruby language.

Comment: Ok, another way: can you show me how I can convert Nokogiri XML to Hash? After that I will use .dig.

Comment: @PeterPenzov, Are you using rails?

Comment: @PeterPenzov, `dig()` example at bottom of my answer.